# Reference another sheet in Formula string SpreadSheetGear

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, spreadsheetgear

As the questions states, I'm trying to reference some cells from one sheet to another. In one sheet I have the Data to populate some other cells in my Principal sheet

In short: DataSheet > Feeds > PrincipalSheet

I'm trying something like:

```
"=Data!$A$1"
```

I've even tried something like:

```
 "=[Book1]Data!$A$1"
```

But still, I can't find the correct code.

I have SpreadSheetGeat 2010 and using C#

Thanks in advance for the help you provide!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the answer, actually, the formula is OK, I was generating the cell ranges with some manual, over the top code, and all that I needed was to put

```
MySheet.Cells[add ranges here].Range.ToString();
```

With this code, SpreadSheet generates automatically in which range you are on in this format :  "=[Book1]Data!$A$1", and is based on the range that you put in .Cells[],

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Spreadsheet gear adds "[Book1]" when I try the following code. It didn't seem to work in excel.

```
MySheet.Cells[add ranges here].Range.ToString();
```

So I manually set the formula Like so:

```
cells[ rowIndex, 2 ].Formula = "=IFERROR('MySheet1'!$E$6,0)";
```